# How can i get timecode for wmv file

Tags: c#, video, wmplib, timecodes

I found WindowsMediaPlayer in WMPLib but not the TimeCode!

Anyone known how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the answer to your question is that you will need to call IWMReaderTimecode::GetTimecodeRangeCount for each stream in your file. Then call IWMReaderTimecode::GetTimecodeRangeBounds for each range in each stream to get the startTimecode and endTimecode of each range.

Comment: Thanks, can you add a sample.
How do you implement this class ?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm mainly a Java programmer. Your probably better asking the question over on the msdn forums http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/categories . I have the idea on how to do it as above but it will take some figuring out to code

Answer (score 0):

Looking at these two articles [Get WMA/WMV meta information in C#](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Media/microsoft.public.windowsmedia.sdk/2005-07/msg00240.html) and [Getting Current Time Code Using Windows Media Player Class in C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/winforms/thread/192cefd5-33e5-4fa3-8051-9b0893160964?persist=True), you could try the following:

```
using WMPLib; // this file is called Interop.WMPLib.dll 

WindowsMediaPlayerClass wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayerClass(); 
IWMPMedia mediaInfo = wmp.newMedia("myfile.wmv"); 

Console.WriteLine("Duration = " + mediaInfo.duration); 

for (int i=0; i<mediaInfo.attributeCount; i++) { 
    Console.WriteLine(mediaInfo.getAttributeName(i) + " = " + 
    mediaInfo.getItemInfo(mediaInfo.getAttributeName(i)) ); 
}
```

or use the `Controls.CurrentPositionString` property to get the current time.

```
Console.WriteLine(wmp.controls.currentPositionString);
```